# Banach spaces over complete fields with their own absolute value

Tags: banach-spaces, absolute-value, ordered-fields

Let $F\hspace{.03 in}$ be a field, and let $E\hspace{.03 in}$ be an ordered subfield of $F$.

Let $\;\; |\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.03 in}| \: : \: F \: \to \: E \;\;$ be such that for all elements $x$ of $E\hspace{.02 in}$, for all elements $y$ and $z$ of $\hspace{.02 in}F$,

$0\leq x \; \implies \; |\hspace{.025 in}x\hspace{.02 in}| = x$

and
$0\leq \left|\hspace{.03 in}y\hspace{.015 in}\right| \;\;\;\;\;$ and $\;\;\;\;\; \left|\hspace{.03 in}y\hspace{.015 in}\right| \cdot \left|\hspace{.02 in}z\hspace{.01 in}\right| \:\: = \:\: \left|\hspace{.03 in}y\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.05 in}z\hspace{.02 in}\right| \;\;\;\;\;$ and $\;\;\;\;\; \left|\hspace{.03 in}y\hspace{-0.04 in}+\hspace{-0.04 in}z\hspace{.02 in}\right| \:\: \leq \:\: \left|\hspace{.03 in}y\hspace{.01 in}\right|+\left|\hspace{.02 in}z\hspace{.01 in}\right|$

.
Additionally, assume that $F$ is [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness) with respect to $\:|\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.03 in}|\:$. $\;\;$ Does it follow that the standard results for Banach spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ ([open mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29), [closed graph theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem), and the version of the [uniform boundedness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) that just uses boundedness, rather than [suprema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum)) hold for "Banach spaces over $\hspace{.02 in}\langle F,\hspace{-0.02 in}|\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.04 in}|\hspace{.02 in}\rangle$"$\hspace{.03 in}$?

Comment: Do you have an example in mind?  And is there a reason you insist that $E\subset F$?

For instance, the rich subject of non-archimedean analysis satisfies many of the properties you are interested in, specifically in the case where $F$ is complete with respect to a norm $F\to \mathbb{R}$, but $F$ does not contain $\mathbb{R}$ as a normed space (e.g. $F=\mathbb{Q}_p$ or $F=\mathbb{C}((t))$, with $|x| = p^{-\rm{ord}_p (x)}$ and $|x| = e^{-\rm{ord}_t (x)}$ respectively).

Comment: I don't insist that $E\subset F$, I just insist that $E\subseteq F$. The only examples I have are when $E=F$; such as fields of formal Laurent series (over ordered fields).

Comment: I read those symbols in the same way.  My question still stands.  What is your example of an interesting "Banach space" over a field of formal Laurent series, that is not better expressed using the real-valued non-archimedean norm I mentioned before?

Comment: [$\ell^1$ or $c_0$ or $c$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) over $\mathbb{R}((t)) \;\;$

Comment: I can see how this could be interesting.  I do think that the theory is not advanced enough for what you want, but if we put the trivial norm on $\mathbb{R}$, then this is standard non-archimedean stuff, and there is lots of material in e.g. Bosch-Güntzer-Remmert, Berkovich, and so on.  In this context, $\mathbb{R}((t))$ with the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}$ should be understood as a non-archimedean field with archimedean residue field, which is similar to a construction of Temkin, but he treats only non-archimedean residue fields.  I don't think anybody has gotten to this case yet.

Comment: But for example, Bosch-Güntzer-Remmert prove the open mapping theorem over nonarchimedean fields (like $\mathbb{R}((t))$ with the trival norm on $\mathbb{R}$, which is a first approximation of your field) in their book, "Non-Archimedean Analysis".

Comment: I now realize that, in my version, $E$ is either non-Archimedean or isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. $\:$ (I also realize that it might be that you found that too simple to mention.) $\:$ Do you know if there are any results for the case of $E = \mathbb{R}\hspace{.02 in}$? $\;\;\;$

Comment: I should mention, in case you're unaware, that there are two definitions of "archimedean", and I've been using the one for normed fields—I should probably say "ultrametric".  But yes, your $E\neq \mathbb{R}$ examples are all non-archimedean in the other sense, the one for ordered fields.

$E=\mathbb{R}$ is a well-understood case: $F=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ are the only options (this is the Gelfand-Mazur theorem).  This is why I suggested that $F$ not be required to contain $E$, as this allows ultrametric fields.

Comment: (though if you drop commutativity, you can also pick up the quaternions with $E=\mathbb{R}$)